# Loading JPG image using jpeglib - incorrect result, tilted image

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm loading JPG image using jpeglib. Sometimes images are loaded correctly and sometimes incorrectly (with no color and tilted). It depends on which image I'm loading. I am using OpenGL to render and display graphics. Below I attach example and my code:

[Picture I want to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIdJb.jpg)

[Incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzh3E.png)

Code:

```
bool JPEGUtil::load(VGByteArray* source, VGByteArray *destination, int &width, int &height) 
{
    source->position = 0;

    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;

    struct ErrorMgr jerr;

    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1] = {0};
    unsigned long location = 0;

    bool ret = false;
    do
    {
        cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr.pub);
        jerr.pub.error_exit = myErrorExit;

        if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer))
        {
            jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
            break;
        }

        jpeg_create_decompress( &cinfo );
        jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, source->getBytes(), source->getBytesAvailable());

        int header = jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

        if (header != 1) {
            break;//error
        }

        cinfo.out_color_space = JCS_RGB;

        /* Start decompression jpeg here */
        jpeg_start_decompress( &cinfo );

        /* init image info */
        width  = cinfo.output_width;
        height = cinfo.output_height;

        unsigned char* data = destination->getBytes();

        /* now actually read the jpeg into the raw buffer */
        /* read one scan line at a time */
        while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height)
        {
            row_pointer[0] = data + location;
            location += cinfo.output_width*cinfo.output_components;
            jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
        }

        jpeg_destroy_decompress( &cinfo );
        ret = true;
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}
```

Again - some pictures are loaded correctly, some as in example. Any ideas? Thanks.